# Multithreaded Single Producer Multiple Consumer Implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I would like to implement a Multiple file downloading with pattern of single producer and multiple consumer.

What I have:
- Code which finds new links to be downloaded in a loop
- When a new link is found - it calls download function
- Download function accepts source file path and destination file path and downloads the file.

What I want to do
- I want to download X number of files simultaneously (I dont know total number of files)
- At any times I should be able to download X files simultaneously - as soon as 1 of the X file finish downloading - the calling function should be able to add new download right away - which in turn downloading right away

- So I have a producer function which keeps adding new download to queue (at any time maximum X downloads)
- Multiple X thread which consumes the downloads and start downloading individually. Once it finishes download - the producer should be able to add new download - which will spawn new thread.

EXAMPLE would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) class is designed to do that.

Also, check this brilliant website about threading:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Reader_Writer_Locks

The example comes from the website above.

```
class SlimDemo
{
  static ReaderWriterLockSlim _rw = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
  static List<int> _items = new List<int>();
  static Random _rand = new Random();

  static void Main()
  {
    new Thread (Read).Start();
    new Thread (Read).Start();
    new Thread (Read).Start();

    new Thread (Write).Start ("A");
    new Thread (Write).Start ("B");
  }

  static void Read()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      _rw.EnterReadLock();
      foreach (int i in _items) Thread.Sleep (10);
      _rw.ExitReadLock();
    }
  }

  static void Write (object threadID)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      int newNumber = GetRandNum (100);
      _rw.EnterWriteLock();
      _items.Add (newNumber);
      _rw.ExitWriteLock();
      Console.WriteLine ("Thread " + threadID + " added " + newNumber);
      Thread.Sleep (100);
    }
  }

  static int GetRandNum (int max) { lock (_rand) return _rand.Next(max); }
}
```

Comment: Producer = Writer, Consumer = Reader. Reader/Writer are common names in threading nomenclature for agents that read or write shared data (downloads queue = _items in the example).

Comment: How to delete thread-safe items in the _items list after it is processed in the Read() method?

Answer (score 5):

For this P/C problem all you need is a `BlockingCollection<T>`.

```
//shared and thread-safe
static BlockingCollection<string> queue = new BlockingCollection<string>(100);

// Producer
queue.Add(fileName);  // will block when full

// Consumer
if (queue.TryTake(out fileName, timeOut))  // waits when empty
  ...
```

You'll want to fine-tune it a little with timeouts and CancellationTokens.

Comment: After you dequeue a item, perform some processing, how can you return a result to the calling process?

Comment: What exactly is the 'calling process' ?

Comment: Im looking at implementing a queue for throttling web requests. So i have a method lets say DownloadUser() from a webservice and the request gets added to a queue to be throttled. How can i return a result back to that method DownloadUser()?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, If consider bottleneck, how to apply it? Let's say we have three consumers.

Comment: @Love - same thing. If the Prod cannot keep up the Cons will wait a lot. But don't ask questions under 2 year old answers.

Comment: Question states "Single producer multiple consumer".  Your example is one-to-one.  When the consumer issues the `TryTake` method, the item is removed from the thread-safe collection.  Other consumers don't have a chance.

Comment: @ajhuddy - other consumers want other items. This answer is valid for multiple consumers. You may be confusing P/C with a Bus.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Concurrent collection for the communication between the boss and its work crew.
Either ConcurrentQueue (if you care about the order) or ConcurrentBag.
The boss adds to ConcurrentQueue (Add method) and the crew takes from the queue (Take method). Let me know if you need code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). This wraps up the method calls very cleanly, and manages your multiple threads for you.

Comment: Are you sure Task Parallel library solves the problem of accessing shared data? Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx at section `Avoid Writing to Shared Memory Locations`.